# synergy on ubunut stopped working

Tags: ubuntu, synergy

I've worked with synergy for a three months now, and today they just stop working, I' using standard `/etc/synergy.conf` file between my two lap tops.

So server config is this:

```
section: screens
        korisnik:
        petarp:
end
section: aliases
        korisnik:
                some ip
        petarp:
                some ip
end
section: links
        korisnik:
                left = petarp
        petarp:
                right = korisnik
end
```

end my Client have similar configuration

```
section: screens
        petarp:
        korisnik:
end
section: aliases
        petarp:
                some ip
        korisnik:
                some ip
end
section: links
        petarp:
                left = korisnik
        korisnik:
                right = petarp
end
```

Now the error that I'm facing is something like this

```
2016-09-23T21:00:02 NOTE: connecting to '1xx.xxx.x.xxx': 1xx.xxx.x.xxx:24800
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.4.12/src/lib/client/CClient.cpp,136
2016-09-23T21:00:02 WARNING: failed to connect to server: Connection refused
    /build/buildd/synergy-1.4.12/src/lib/synergy/CClientApp.cpp,372
```

I've tried purging synergy and starting everything again, but that didn't change a thing, tried updating, restarting, still the same connection problem. I'm using `ubuntu 14.04`, can someone help me understand this error, and over come this, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

"Connection refused" usually indicates an authentication problem or that the server did not allow a TCP 3-way handshake to occur. Most likely general reasons: 1) the server is not listening on the port the client is trying to communicate to (or isn't listening at all). 2) a firewall (on the server or in the network) is not permitting the traffic. 3) password mismatch

If you haven't already done so check for general network connectivity between client and server (ping from one to the other) and verify IP addresses / port numbers in your configuration. Also check that the password hasn't been misspelled.

You can use netstat to verify that the server is listening on the port you expect it to be.

```
$netstat -ltup
```

You can check your firewall rules in Linux.

```
#iptables -L
```

You can get more details from Synergy by increasing the log detail

```
Edit > Settings > Logging Level drop-down menu
```

Good luck troubleshooting!

Comment: I've restarted my router due to some connection problem, and find out that my `ip` changed, so now it is working ;)